# Reading every second and fourth line of an input file and perform text processing using python

Tags: python, python-itertools, text-processing

Normally I would get my second and fourth line using `itertools`

```
secondline = itertools.islice(input_open, 1, None, 4)
fourthline = itertools.islice(input_open, 3, None, 4)
```

and perform `for line in secondline` or `for line in fourthline` to process each 2nd line or fourth line separately.

Is there a way to process every 2nd and 4th line at the same time? I want to perform some text processing on every 2nd and 4th line and do some math between them.

UPDATE
What I meant by every 2nd and every 4th line:

```
  line0
  line1  2nd line
  line2   
  line3  4th line
  line4
  line5  2nd line
  line6  
  line7  4th line
  ...
```

But I figured might as well just use `enumerate` and do a comparison of `i % 4 == 1` and `i % 4 == 3` to get them. Much simpler I suppose

Comment: I don't understand your question. A file has at most one second and att most one fourth line... given that you know how to obtain them what are you asking us? Do you have a list of files and you have to take all the second lines from all the files and do something with them and then all the fourth lines and do something with them? Or do you have a list of file and for each file you want to do something with the second and fourth line? You might be interested into the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/fileinput.html) module, but without more information this is not clear.

Comment: It's every second and every fourth line..not the second and the fourth line..

Comment: Isn't *every fourth line* a subset of *every second line*?

Answer (score 1):

One way to obtain pairs of "second" line, "fourth" line is to just take an `islice` with step `2` and then `zip`it with itself:

```
lines = islice(input_file, 1, None, 2)

for second, fourth in zip(lines, lines):
```

This works because `zip` first calls the `__next__` method on the first argument, which obtains the "second" line and advances the iterator, then moves to the second argument and calls `__next__` again obtaining the "fourth" line and advancing the iterator again.

Example with numbers:

```
>>> seq = iter(range(22))
>>> numbers = islice(seq, 1, None, 2)
>>> for num1, num2 in zip(numbers, numbers):
...     print(num1, num2)
... 
1 3
5 7
9 11
13 15
17 19
# Note: missing number 21!
```

---

Note that if the last "second" line has no "fourth" line following it because the file is too short, it wont be present in the output.

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
def 2_and_4(fh):
    first = fh.readline()
    second = fh.readline()
    third = fh.readline()
    fourth = fh.readline()
    yield second, fourth
```

Make it a generator